# Searching if Linked List is Empty

Tags: c++, nodes

So this is related to a homework assignment, but I'm not going to just dump it here. I really want to learn c++, I'm just slow on the upkeep in nodes for some reason. My question is related to check if a linked list is empty or not.

I have this beginning code:

```
void add_node(node*& head_ptr, const int& payload)
{
 node* my_first_node = new node();
my_first_node->data = payload;
my_first_node->next = nullptr;


}
```

with this in the header file

```
struct node {
int data;
node* next;
};
```

I'm wondering if I should do a while loop before my add function, or as part of it? I'm a little lost on just getting that part out of the way, but I'm sure I'll get it once that happens.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `add_node()` supposed to add to the end of the linked list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you only have the head pointer then you need to traverse it until the end node.

First you should check that the `head_ptr` exists.

```
if (head_ptr == nullptr)
    // assign your first node to the head pointer
```

otherwise you need to get to the end of the list. Since this is homework, how about some psuedo code.

```
make a node of interest, call it end_node
while we are not at the end //How can we tell if we are at the end (hint you assign the 
                            // next in your add already check for this)

    move to the next node (interest_node = interest_node->next)
end
```

Now we are at the end node so you can just add your new node on the end.

Hint (you may want to check for broken linked lists ie. circular links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
head_ptr->next = my_first_node;
```

inside "add_node" function

this will make your head_ptr add a "real" new node.

and for your question (loop before add_node)

just doing something like

```
while(head_ptr != nullptr){
... //your code (maybe you can backup the last node in here?)

// write code for head ptr = next node 
}
```

But remember to backup your "real" head_ptr before you assign "next" to your head_ptr.

Otherwise you can't get it back